# Share resources between php web client application and c# .net desktop application

Tags: c#, php, .net, resources, share

I have a web application developed in php and a second (desktop) app developed in C# .net 4.5. 
The web application holds several information which I need to share with the desktop application, process the data in the desktop app and return new data to the web app.

First, I had in mind a file transfer. a) web app uploads a file on the computer, then desktop app reads that file and after processing it saves a new file on local disk. The human then returns to the web app, presses a submit button, the web app loads the new file and deals with it. -> There are too many jobs to do, it has to be simple...

Second, I could connect to the same database as my web app (MySQL), but the database has only local access policy and there are more synchronization problems about the data that the web client reads in that moment in time. I have to sync the returned data from the desktop app with the data in web app.

Third, ... are there any technologies to share data in memory, like MemoryMappedFiles? (attention, is about web client app, not server app).

Any ideas are highly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: create a php script that access the database and echo the data as json or xml .. then from your desktop app make an http call to that script and parse the xml or json response and use the data in your local desktop app.

Comment: and then, step 2, from my desktop app I have to send data back to web client side ..

Comment: well, you can send a post request with any data you want to a certain php script on the server, then the php script well receive the post data and insert it into the database .

Comment: Thanks a lot..I will search for some examples!